# Set flags using formula field based on Lead records created date

Tags: formula-field

I need to create formula field Before 5 years(2013) lead records are created for that i want to set yellow color flag, 
& In between 2 years(2013-2016) to 5 years lead records are created for that i want to set green color flag, 
& In between 1 years(2016-2017) to 2nd year lead records are created for that i want to set blue color flag, 
& In between 6 months (from 22-10-2018 till now) to 1 year lead records are created for that i want to set red color flag
I tried this but it is showing errors,Can any one help me

```
IF(FLOOR((TODAY()- Sales_Order_Date__c ))> 184 && 
FLOOR(( TODAY()- Sales_Order_Date__c )) >360 && 
FLOOR(( TODAY()- Sales_Order_Date__c )) >1825, 
IMAGE("/resource/blue", "Yellow",30,30)||
IMAGE("/resource/green", "green",30,30)||
IMAGE("/resource/red1", "red1",30,30)|| 
IMAGE("/resource/blue", "blue",30,30))
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to interpret formula logic if you use indentation.

```
IF(
    FLOOR((TODAY()- Sales_Order_Date__c)) > 184 && 
    FLOOR((TODAY()- Sales_Order_Date__c)) > 360 && 
    FLOOR((TODAY()- Sales_Order_Date__c ))> 1825, 

    IMAGE("/resource/blue", "Yellow",30,30) || 
    IMAGE("/resource/green", "green",30,30) ||
    IMAGE("/resource/red1", "red1",30,30)   || 
    IMAGE("/resource/blue", "blue",30,30)
)
```

This formula won't compile, because you're only supplying two parameters to the `IF()` function.

The logic also doesn't make sense. When you `&&` your three conditions together, they all have to be `TRUE`, which means in this case it will only be `TRUE` for the largest condition, `> 1825`. Your `IF()` statements should test one or more conditions sequentially and provide two parameters, one to be the result if `TRUE` and one to be the result if `FALSE`. Combining `IMAGE()` calls with `||` does not make sense.

You probably want a formula that has this structure:

```
IF(
    TODAY() - Sales_Order_Date__c > LARGEST_CONDITION,
    IMAGE(), // This is for if the condition is TRUE
    IF( // If the largest condition is FALSE, test the next largest.
        TODAY() - Sales_Order_Date__c > NEXT_LARGEST_CONDITION,
        IMAGE(), // If true
        IF(
            // test the next condition, and so on
        )
    )
)
```

The final `IF()` function would provide two parameters, one for matching the last possible condition and one as a default if that too is false. The default can of course be a blank value.